# Semi-Advanced T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is my scenario:

I have 2 current tables (We'll call them DimA and DimB):

DimA has 2 columns (Key, ZipCode)
DimB has 5 columns (FirstName, LastName, Address, ZipCode, Key)

I need to:

```
 INSERT INTO DimB(Key) VALUES
     (SELECT Column(Key) FROM DimA WHERE dimA.ZipCode = dimB.ZipCode)
```

What is the absolute best way to go about making this work?

Comment: It would help if you could add a little sample demonstrating the state of the data before and after the query.  Do you want to INSERT into DimB from DimA?  Which fields?

Comment: Dave, it looks as though Joel's answer worked for me. I was trying to UPDATE a table that already existed. Every row was filled in except the KEY, which is a new column. I should have been UPDATING rather than INSERTING. Thank you for your time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`. Otherwise, the `dimA.ZipCode = dimB.ZipCode` expression could never be true.

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Key = a.Key
FROM DimA a
INNER JOIN DimB b on b.ZipCode = a.ZipCode
```

Comment: Joel, this was my mistake. I don't know why I was trying to INSERT when I should have been UPDATING. I have been looking at my code for way too long and just couldn't connect why it wasn't working. I greatly appreciate your quick response and help in making this work! Thank you again!